# ¿Cómo crear un servidor web en una máquina virtual?

Tags: aplicación-web, debian

Tengo una VM Debian con un adaptador a la NAT y otro a la red Host-Only. He instalado el servidor web *nginx* mediante el comando `apt-get install nginx`.
Me gustaría saber como tengo que configurar *nginx* para que en mi propio PC  al acceder en el navegador a la IP de la red Host-Only de mi VM, me saliera la página del servidor web.
Aunque sea para empezar que se mostrara únicamente la página de prueba de *nginx* de momento sólo querría saber ese paso importante.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias formas de acceder en tu red local a la maquina virtual que mencionas, unas de las mas fáciles (y comunes) es configurando el adaptador como BRIDGED adapter. este procedimiento hace que se le asigne a tu maquina virtual una dirección local de tu red (ejemplo si es pc tiene la ip 192.168.1.100 es posible que a tu maquina virtual se le asigne la dirección ip 192.168.1.101)

Esta es una opción que te puede funcionar fácilmente.

Otra opción es configurar virtual box para que haga una apertura de puertos (en el adaptador que tiene por configuración NAT * ver imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer la REDIRECCION de puertos, puedes acceder a la IP de tu maquina local desde el navegador y ver la información del servidor NGINX de tu maquina virtual.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay muchas formas de abrir los puertos en este tipo de maquinas, si me suministras mas información de lo que quieres hacer, te puedo ayudar

Cordial saludo.

Comment: Ampliando un poco la informacion del comentario de x4mp73r. la documentacion de virtual box explica en que casos se utiliza cada uno (Bridged, nat y host only) https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat "The disadvantage of NAT mode is that, much like a private network behind a router, the virtual machine is invisible and unreachable from the outside internet; you cannot run a server this way unless you set up port forwarding "  en resumen dice que en NAT toca hacer PORT FORWARDING.

Answer (score 0):

Que yo sepa solo tienes que configurar **un adaptador de red** y que sea NAT y ya no tienes que configurar nada. Corre el servidor y desde tu pc escribe `http://10.0.2.2` esto es lo mismo que `localhost` en tu máquina virtual ya que es el gateway por default.

Comment: No funciona....

Comment: Debes utilizar bridge, no nat.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Pues da una respuesta con lo que dices para aprendamos todos :)

Comment: [La respuesta de @DanielFerrans](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10787/227) lo explica y está muy bien documentada. No creo que tenga necesidad de agregar una respuesta adicional.